# React Native Pressables - Creating a native look button

Tags: react-native, pressable

If you create a React Native `<Button>`, it renders as a UIButton in iOS and an android.widget.Button in android. This means that it looks different on different platforms.

[image: Button and Pressable on android]
[image: Button and Pressable on ios]

What about `Pressable`s? What is the simplest way to create an iOS button on iOS and an Android button on Android without resorting to a 3rd partly npm library?

Comment: Pressable is simply a wrapper component. You can put your `Button` inside of it to get the native styling (i.e. `<Pressable> <Button title='Save' /> </Pressable>`)

Comment: https://medium.com/@mahyarmohammadi/react-native-pressable-vs-touchable-5fec6b332f15 - has more info, might help..

Comment: @nbokmans I confirmed that the `<Button>` inside the `<Pressable>` will intercept the onPress event. It never bubbles to the `<Pressable>`'s onPress. So that doesn't work easily. Thanks, though.